# Receive socket with "dynamic" byte size

Tags: c#, sockets

I have an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` and I serialize its contents and send it using socket. Follow the code:

```
private const int Port = 3762;
private static SocketPermission permission = new SocketPermission(NetworkAccess.Accept, TransportType.Tcp, "", Port);
private static IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty);
private static IPAddress ipAddress = ipEntry.AddressList[0];
private static IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Port);

Socket sTransmissao = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var binary = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
    binary.Serialize(stream, TransmissaoPendencias);
    byte[] bArray = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Read(bArray, 0, (int)stream.Length);

    sTransmissao.Connect(ipAddress, Port);
    sTransmissao.Send(bArray);
}
```

But the byte length will change with the amount of items in my collection.

What is a viable solution to retrieving this information on the client side?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to transmit the size before sending the array so that the other end knows how much to read.

Comment: How can I do that? I would need two listeners ? I'm relative new to sockets. Could you give me an example or link me to a tutorial of it ? Thanks.

Comment: After some minutes I realized how stupid it was what I commented. Just now I noticed the SendBufferSize and ReceiveBufferSize. Thanks dude and sorry for the last comment.

Comment: @AndréSilva: That is not at all what I meant.  Before transmitting the bytes, transmit the size as a four-byte integer.

Comment: Yeah, your answer actually opened my mind to search for headers and found what I was looking for, I guess you noticed I'm terrible at explaining things but that actually helped me.

Thanks again.